# Add class to children on click

Tags: html, jquery

```
    <ul class="categories-menu">
      <li class="cat-item">
        <a href="url_to_category_A">A</a>
        
        <ul class="children">
          <li class="cat-item">
             <i class="fas fa-plus open"><-- This elment should expand children on click -->
             <a href="url_to_category_A_child">A-CHILD</a>

          </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="categories-menu">
      <li class="cat-item">
        <a href="url_to_category_A">A</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li class="cat-item">
             <i class="fas fa-plus open"> <-- This elment should expand children on click -->
             <a href="url_to_category_A_child">A-CHILD</a>

          </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

I try to add class open to submenu, when I click in specific .
Now all items with class submenu will open when I click on .
I want to open just closest submenu.

```
(function($){


    $('.open').click(function(){

            ($(this).next().find('.children').length)
            $('.children').addClass('opened');

    });



})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("open");

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children')[0].toggleClass('opened');
    }));
```

How to add slideDown/slideUp.
I have console error: slideDown is undefined when I try add it.

Comment: Why html classes don't match jquery classes?

Comment: Ok now html classes match jquery classes

Comment: `($(this).next().find('.children').length)` – what is that supposed to achieve? `$('.children').addClass('opened');` – you are selecting _all_ elements with the class `children` here, you did not limit this to any specific parent element at all.

Comment: _“How to add slideDown/slideUp. I have console error:”_ - Don’t ask about multiple different things at once. And don’t ask vague “how to, I get error” questions either. Show the code you tried, and quote the exact error message.